# High & Low Numbers From A String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

Good evening,

I'm trying to solve a problem on Codewars:

*In this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.*

*Example:*

```
high_and_low("1 2 3 4 5")  # return "5 1"
high_and_low("1 2 -3 4 5") # return "5 -3"
high_and_low("1 9 3 4 -5") # return "9 -5"
```

*Notes:*

*All numbers are valid Int32, no need to validate them.*
*There will always be at least one number in the input string.*
*Output string must be two numbers separated by a single space, and highest number is first.*

I came up with the following solution however I cannot figure out why the method is only returning "542" and not "-214 542". I also tried using #at, #shift and #pop, with the same result.

Is there something I am missing? I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I would like to understand why this is happening.

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
    numberArray = numbers.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i).sort
    numberArray[-1]
    numberArray[0]
end

high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

*EDIT*

I also tried this and receive a failed test "Nil":

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
  numberArray = numbers.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i).sort
  puts "#{numberArray[-1]}" + " " + "#{numberArray[0]}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you Cary! I edited the question. Best regards.

Comment: To put the result in the form you've now specified you can just tack `join(' ')` onto the second of @Yu's suggestions: `numbers.split.minmax_by(&:to_i).join(' ') #=> "-214 542"`, though I think leaving it as an array would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When omitting the `return` statement, a function will only return the result of the last expression within its body. To return both as an Array write:

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
    numberArray = numbers.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i).sort
    return numberArray[0], numberArray[-1]
end

puts high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
# => [-214, 542]
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using sort would be inefficient for big arrays. Instead, use [`Enumerable#minmax`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax):

```
numbers.split.map(&:to_i).minmax
# => [-214, 542]
```

Or use [`Enumerable#minmax_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) if you like result to remain strings:

```
numbers.split.minmax_by(&:to_i)
# => ["-214", "542"]
```